# Use custom HTML tags in Vue without v-pre or ignoredElements

Tags: html, vue.js, tags, vue-component, web-component

I would like to use custom tags in Vue, not a component just tags to give a more meaningul sense to my HTML. I used `v-pre` what's fine on elements without children. How can I do it in elements with children?

```
<template>
  <g-search v-pre>
    <g-title v-pre>My Search</g-title>
    <input v-model="text">
    <Films :films="films"></Films>
  </g-search>
</template>
```

If I remove the `v-pre` everthing works fine but I have again errors that say:

```
[Vue warn]: Unknown custom element
```

Can I do it without creating a list with my ignored elements?

```
Vue.config.ignoredElements = [
  'g-search',
  'g-title'
]
```

Comment: If the custom element names all follow a pattern you could use a RegExp with `ignoredElements`.

Comment: Really good idea skirtle. I will use that for now : ) thanks a lot. I'd like to see Vue supporting custom tags in the near future or at least a default way to avoid these errors in normal HTML.